# Calculate the climatological mean of values stored in excel /.CSV files according to the day of the year in python

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a data X of all the days of the years 2000 to 2005 in a .CSV file.

I want the mean of X values of the same date of different years i.e. mean of X value of 01-jan-2000, 01-jan-2001, 01-jan-2002, 01-jan-2003, 01-jan-2004 and 01-jan-2005 then 02-jan-2000, 02-jan-2001, 02-jan-2002, 02-jan-2003, 02-jan-2004 and 02-jan-2005 and so on for all the days.

I used: `dataframe.groupby('dateindex.dayofyear').mean()['X']` command for the same purpose but unfortunately it gave wrong mean values from 29th february in the leap years and from 1st march in the non leap years.

An example with dates, X values and Mean(expected outcome for the example data):

```
   Date        X       Mean(Expected Outcome)
01-01-2000     1         (1+4)/2=2.5
02-01-2000     2              3.5
03-01-2000     3              4.5
01-01-2001     4              2.5
02-01-2001     5              3.5
03-01-2001     6              4.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.Series.dt.strftime`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['Mean'] = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime("%m%d"))["X"].transform("mean")
print(df)
```

Or simply using the `str`:

```
df['Mean'] = df.groupby(df["Date"].str[:5])["X"].transform("mean")
```

Output:

```
        Date  X  Mean
0 2000-01-01  1   2.5
1 2000-01-02  2   3.5
2 2000-01-03  3   4.5
3 2001-01-01  4   2.5
4 2001-01-02  5   3.5
5 2001-01-03  6   4.5
```